# Using ICC Profiles in as3/flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, color-profile, color-management

I am creating a flash site where someone can customize a canvas. Then they can preview this canvas on the product. Because of the way monitors display colors, we wanted to try to embed an icc color profile in the previewed image so the user can get a better idea of what the end product will look like. For instance, if they upload something with a really bright red, the preview will show this in a more realistic color to what can be printed on the canvas. This preview is generated on the fly in a flex application using as3.

How I could go about doing this? Is this possible?  I realize I could fake something by manipulating colors in flash, but the printer that prints the canvas is able to export an icc profile that will be more accurate. So, I'd like to use that if possible.